# Install Issues on Delphi XE2 (Advantage Delphi Components)

Tags: delphi, advantage-database-server

[image: Advantage Delphi Component Error]

Installed Advantage Delphi Components on Delphi XE2 (Windows 7 Pro).  We're getting error when opening Delphi XE2 showing the above dialog box.

Tried compiling the adsDXE2dstudio package but failed.

What are we missing here?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: What does "tried compiling...but failed" mean? What "failed"? What error messages do you get? When you write "it failed", the very next thing you should type is **exactly** what that means, along with the **exact** error messages you got, including any memory addresses or compiler errors. We can't see your screen from here or read your mind, so if you don't tell us we can't know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You failed to provide a lot of information, so this is a pretty generic answer.

First, if you *ever* answered yes to this dialog, you'll need to edit the registry and remove the package name from `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Embarcadero\BDS\9.0\Disabled Packages`. If something is listed there, the IDE doesn't remove it once you reinstall to fix the problem, and it will keep disappearing from the component palette when the IDE is re-started.

First, make sure the package actually exists. Use Windows Explorer, and do a search for it. If it's not there, the installation failed. Re-run it, making sure you're logged in as an administrator. You may want to use Control Panel to make sure it's uninstalled first to remove any remnants.

If the package (BPL) exists on your machine, the folder it's located in isn't on your system PATH. The Delphi installer puts it there automatically, but something may have changed it for some reason. (See below on how to check.) For instance, if you installed as one user, chose "Install for me only" instead of "Install for all users of this computer", and then logged in as a different user, started the IDE, and then installed Advantage.

The IDE by default puts 32-bit packages in the `C:\Users\Public\Documents\RAD Studio\9.0\Bpl` folder (32-bit packages, which includes all of the design-time packages) and `C:\Users\Public\Documents\RAD Studio\9.0\Bpl\Win64` folders (64-bit runtime packages). These two folders should be on your system `PATH`, and the Advantage packages should be in those locations.

You can check the `PATH` by using the `Start button`, right-clicking `Computer` in the right pane, and choosing `Advanced System Settings` (left side when Control Panel opens), and then clicking on the `Environmental Variables` button in the resulting dialog).

Comment: Thank you Mr. Ken White.  It helped figuring out what's going on.  (It's been a while since D5 so I'm a little bit rusty trying to port this app to Delphi XE2).

Comment: The installation of adsdelphi.exe (ADS Delphi Comp) doesn't compile the bpl outright.  Running D-XE2 as administrator, navigating to the source loc and building the package created the bpl on the default location that you mentioned.  Instead of mucking around the package file, I just copied the bpl to where it is expected and it worked.

I apologize for the vagueness of the question as I was hoping some ADS guys checks this site.

Thanks again.

Comment: Also, dcu's need to be built and transferred to the proper location expected.